# Unit Test: System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, httpcalloutmock

**BACKGROUND**

I am testing a method that results in **two** external calls out to an API.

I have this Apex unit test:

```
@isTest
public static void createInvoice_Success(){

    // arrange      
    StaticResourceCalloutMock contactMock = getStaticResourceCalloutMock(200, 'ContactsMock');
    StaticResourceCalloutMock invoiceMock = getStaticResourceCalloutMock(200, 'InvoicesMock');

    Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> mocksMap = new Map<String, HttpCalloutMock>();

    mocksMap.put('https://api.example.com/api/2.0/Contacts', contactMock);
    mocksMap.put('https://api.example.com/api/2.0/Invoices', invoiceMock);

    HttpCalloutMock mocks = new MultiRequestMock(mocksMap);

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mocks);

    Appointment__c appointment = TestDataFactory.createAppointment();
    Id invoiceId = TestDataFactory.createInvoice(appointment);
    Id invoiceLineId = TestDataFactory.createInvoiceLine(invoiceId, appointment.Id);

    CustomAction.Request request = new CustomAction.Request();
    request.invoiceId = invoiceId;

    // act
    Test.startTest();
    List<CustomAction.Response> responseList = CustomAction.execute(new List<CustomAction.Request> {request});
    Test.stopTest();

    // assert
    System.assertEquals(true, responseList[0].isSuccess);
}
```

There is also a `@testSetup` method:

```
@testSetup
    static void testSetup () {

        insert new Custom_Settings__c(
            SetupOwnerId = Userinfo.getOrganizationId(),
            Key__c = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            Endpoint__c = 'https://api.example.com/api/2.0/'
        );

    }
```

Additionally, the test method uses this helper method:

```
private static StaticResourceCalloutMock getStaticResourceCalloutMock(Integer statusCode, String staticResourceName) {

    StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();

    mock.setStaticResource(staticResourceName);
    mock.setStatusCode(statusCode);
    mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return mock;
}
```

The class `CustomAction` has an `Invocable Method` such that it may be used by `Process Builder`

**QUESTION**

Why am I getting this error message:

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

What *uncommitted* work is it referring to?

What is the solution to making this unit test work?

Comment: Is CustomAction.execute a queueable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue related to the order of actions:

1. Make a call out to the API
2. Save the result of API call
3. Make another call out to the API
4. Save result of the second API call

I fixed the unit test by only doing one API call out per `Invocable Method`

Answer (score 0):

Do you do some CRUD operation before doing your callout ? If this is the case, then you need to do your callout in a future method. You cannot do CRUD operations before doing a callout in the same context. Making your callout in a future method will create a separate context for your callout.